# Carbonyl chloride from stabilized chloroform treated with hydrogen peroxide

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, redox

In our lab, chloroform contains 0.5–1% ethanol to prevent it from producing carbonyl chloride when exposed to UV light.

Will the following reaction occur using such chloroform?

$$\ce{CHCl3 + H2O2 -> HCl + H2O + COCl2 ^}$$

Comment: I can't find any evidence that carbonyldichloride (phosgene) is formed this way. However, this paper discusses the reaction of chloroform with hydrogen peroxide. It is behind a paywall so I can only see the abstract  https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/09593339009384930?journalCode=tent20

Comment: The source is from here: https://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%85%89%E6%B0%94    It's unavailable in English.